# Update that splits one column into two?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm in a bit of a time crunch. I have a table with 2 columns. firstName, and lastName.

The data imported into SQL had both first and last name inside of the firstName column.

Is there a quick way to update the table to put everything before the first space into the lastName, and everything after the space into the firstName column? I know I could export, and do this via excel, but it in close to production time so I would rather not risk issues.

I have looked at a couple different split posts on here, but those do not involve updating at the same time.

Comment: Are you sure you can simply use the first space as the anchor for the split and it be accurate? What about names like Mary Ann Smith?

Comment: You can use the mysql string functions on the right side of the update's set assignments. Set assignments are handled left to right, so make sure to assign the "end" to last name before removing it from first name.

Comment: Note that however you split the names, you're going to get inaccuracies.  "John Smith" is easy to split on spaces, but what about "Mary Ann Summers" or "Edward Van Halen"?  The first should split on the second space, and the second on the first space.  Or what about "Mary Ann Van Halen"?  I'm not saying not to proceed, but be aware that splitting names is an inexact science.

Comment: Is there always  a single space divides the first name and last name?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
UPDATE
   table
SET
   lastname = SUBSTRING(firstName, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', firstName) - 1),
   firstName= SUBSTRING(firstName, CHARINDEX(' ', firstName) + 1, LEN(firstName))
```

Comment: It looks like it would do the trick, but my MySQL says that ChARINDEX isn't a function. is this for MySQL or MSSQL?

Comment: that is [MSSQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186323.aspx), you'll need to use MySQL's [INSTR](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) and adjust accordingly (i.e. swap the parameters).

Comment: Nicarus, what is the reason for `'_'` instead of `' '`? Also, it looks like you are putting the first name in the lastname field, and trying to put the last name in the firstname one (and the `LEN()` call is unnecessary and a bit "iffy").

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>MySQL</kbd>

**Demonstration:**

```
SET @str := 'Robert Optional Dickey';

SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',-1),1) AS lastName,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',-1) AS firstName;
```

**Output:**

```
lastName            firstName
Robert Optional     Dickey
```

**Update Query:**

```
UPDATE your_table
SET lastName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',-1),1),
firstName = SUBSTRING_INDEX(@str,' ',-1);
```

**Note:** It will work for any number spaces inside the full name.It just considers the string after the last space as first name.